# Handling Arbitrary Depth Recursive Updates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, recursion

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using MongoDB to store a hierarchical data structure consisting of expressions and their arguments. Each expression can have arguments, and these arguments can themselves have expressions. The structure can have arbitrary depths.

I need to perform a recursive operation where I want to rename all occurrences of expression names from "a" to "b". While I'm aware of MongoDB's powerful update operators, I'm struggling to find a suitable one-liner updateMany operation to handle this kind of recursive update.

I've tried exploring solutions with array filters and the $[] operator, but it seems that this approach doesn't easily lend itself to handling the arbitrary depth of nesting in my data structure.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggest an alternative approach on how to efficiently achieve this recursive update for arbitrary depth structures in MongoDB? Is it necessary to retrieve the data, process it in my programming language, and then update the documents back into the database, or is there a more direct way within MongoDB itself?

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "expressions": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "b",
          "expressions": [
            {
              "name": "a",
              "arguments": [
                {
                  "name": "c",
                  "expressions": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function and run it in [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/function/):

For demonstration, I modified your document a bit:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "expressions": {
      "name": "a",
      "arguments": {
         "name": "b",
         "expressions": {
            "name": "a",
            "arguments": {
               "name": "c",
               "expressions": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: 1 },
   [{
      $set: {
         expressions: {
            $function: {
               body:
                  function recurse(input, property, val, newVal) {
                     var result = {};
                     for (prop in input) {
                        result[prop] = input[prop];
                        if (typeof input[prop] === 'object') {
                           result[prop] = recurse(input[prop], property, val, newVal);
                        } else if (prop === property && result[prop] === val) {
                           result[prop] = newName;
                        }
                     }
                     return result;
                  },
               args: ["$expressions", 'name', 'a', 'b'],
               lang: "js"
            }
         }
      }
   }],
   { returnNewDocument: true }
);
```

will return

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "expressions": {
      "name": "b",
      "arguments": {
         "name": "b",
         "expressions": {
            "name": "b",
            "arguments": {
               "name": "c",
               "expressions": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you have a mix of `Array` and `Object`, then you need to add `Array.isArray(input[prop])` in your function and loop over all items.